# Angular 5 - Updating Model from Form

Tags: forms, angular5, updates, crud

i'm new to Angular 5 and i'm trying to make a CRUD.
i'm struggling with the "update" part.

what i'd want to do is, in my form, getting back the data of the Model to fill the input text with, then, when i click on the update button, updating the all model.

I tried so many thing from tuts and forums that i'm completly lost now. So here is what i have.

html :

```
<form [formGroup]="policyForm" (ngSubmit)="update()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="policyName">
  </mat-form-field>
... Many other inputs
  <button type="submit" color="primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

component :

```
export class PolicyUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  policyModel: PolicyModel;
  policyId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  policyForm: FormGroup;
  formBuilder: FormBuilder;

  constructor(

    private policyService: PolicyService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder

  ) {

    this.policyService.get(this.policyId)
      .subscribe(policy => this.policyModel = policy);
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.policyForm = this.fb.group({
      policyName: [this.policyModel.name, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  update(id: number) {
    id = this.policyId;
    this.policyModel = <PolicyModel>this.policyForm.value;
    this.policyService.update(id, this.policyModel).subscribe(res => {
      this.router.navigate(['/policies', id, 'get']);
    }, (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    }
    );

  }

}
```

service :

```
 /**
   * Update a policy with new parameters
   * @param pm PolicyModel
   */
  update(id: number, pm: PolicyModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put<PolicyModel>(`${environment.baseApiUrl}/${environment.apiVersion}/policies/${id}`, {pm});
  }
```

any help would be nice.. thanks guys!

Comment: In html "(ngSubmit)="update()"" method does not have parameter. But in the method itself accept parameter "update(id: number) "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code according to this.

```
<form [formGroup]="policyForm"  >
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="policyName">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button color="primary" (click)="update()">Update</button>
</form>
```

Add subscription to detect form changes.

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.createForm();

        this.policyForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
          (data) => {
            if (JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify({})) {
              this.policyModel.name = data.policyName;
            }
          });
      }

      createForm() {
        this.policyForm = this.fb.group({
          policyName: [this.policyModel.name]
        });
      }

       update(id) {
       this.policyModel.id = id;
       id = this.policyId;
   this.policyService.update(id, this.policyModel)//.subscribe(res => {
     this.router.navigate(['/policies', id, 'get']);
    }, (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    }
    );
      }
```

Sample code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwt91u

Comment: Hi Supun, sorry for the delay, pc died this week-end cause of thunder so had to wait for work to see the answers. i don't understand the update(id) method you posted, could you please explain it to me? how is the data passed to the service ?

Comment: + with the exact code you posted, i get this : `PolicyUpdateComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at PolicyUpdateComponent.push../src/app/components/policy/policy-update/policy-update.component.ts.PolicyUpdateComponent.createForm (policy-update.component.ts:47)
    at PolicyUpdateComponent.push../src/app/components/policy/policy-update/policy-update.component.ts.PolicyUpdateComponent.ngOnInit (policy-update.component.ts:35)`

Comment: @j0w I have just added a dummy update method only for the demo purpose. You can replace it by your update method.

And regarding the error you have posted, you need to create a PolicyModel object fist. Check my sample code again. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwt91u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yeah, finally found the error. my model was an interface and not a class... so now it seems that the binding between model and view is working. + i modified the update to make a call from the service. Thanks a lot! :) Now I have to understand why the update doesn't not work. the policy model in api... :')

Comment: I surely can :) Thanks again for your time !